# i18n translations do not work when error page is inluded by ACS commons error page handler

Tags: adobe, aem

The i18n part of error page does not work when response from the error page designated by the **errorPages** property is included by the [error page handler](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/errorpagehandler.html).

The translations work fine when the error page is requested directly . However it fails to pick up any values and falls back to the key when the response of the error page is included by [includeUsingGET](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/commons/errorpagehandler/ErrorPageHandlerService.java) method

Example :

`com.day.cq.i18n.I18n i18n = new com.day.cq.i18n.I18n(slingRequest.getResourceBundle(currentPage.getLanguage(false))); 
String translatedValue = i18n.get("key");
out.write(translatedValue);`

1. Output when error page is **accessed directly** with a get request -> translatedValue
2. Output when the error page is **included by errorpagehandler** on a 404
   -> key

The value of `currentPage.getLanguage(false).getLanguage()` is same in both the cases.

NOTE : I have already created an [issue](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/issues/382) on github regarding this, asking a question here as stackoverflow has  larger audience.

Answer (score 3):

Please, try add config /apps/sling/config/org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
   jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
   service.ranking="-10000"
   sling.filter.scope="[REQUEST,ERROR]"/>
```

Also you can do this config in the "Adobe Experience Manager Web Console
Configuration" (http://example.com:4502/system/console/configMgr).

Comment: To which of all options there should it be added? Did you try this workaround?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out doing it in the CRXDE environment.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer.  I am, however, noticing that when I specify the `service.ranking`, Sling seems to fail at parsing the value (-10000; I've tried as String and Long) and sets the service ranking to 0.  If I remove the `service.ranking` property, Sling sets the service ranking to -700.  Ideas?

Comment: This was very odd, but seemingly related to [SLING-2477](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-2477).  The issue appears to be that Sling and JCR support different data types, and that OSGi configuration requires that service.ranking be an integer.  I've solved the previously described ranking issue by creating a `/apps/sling/config/org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.config` flat file (2 lines): `service.ranking=I"-10000" \n
sling.filter.scope=["REQUEST","ERROR"]`

Comment: I am guessing you are using 5.6, that's why the fix in that ticket isn't available. Glad my answer helped you.

Comment: 5.6.1, but I don't understand.  SLING-2477 does not appear to be fixed.  Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

At least in version 5.5 we encountered this problem for any page that resulted in an error page getting loaded.  We did not find a good solution.  This goes beyond the ACS commons error page and seems to be an issue internal to CQ5.

You are likely going to have to write your own code to load the bundle OUTSIDE of the sling request.  I would suggest writing your own OSGI service for this and calling that instead of the the slingRequest.getResourceBundle() approach.

Comment: Hi, found a solution without the need to write a new bundle, but just editing the i18n filter config.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit your org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.config, adding the following line (without spaces):

```
sling.filter.scope=["REQUEST","ERROR"]
```

Comment: This answer provides a working solution, whereas the top solution made the service.ranking change.  See my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

As [Rampant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918278/rampant) says , it is a Bug with the application and has nothing to do with ACS-commons error page handler. The bug was in Sling ([link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-2705)) , i18n filter which loads the correct resourceBundle was not firing for error scope. The issue has been corrected in r1430633. Looks like this fix hasn't made its way to 5.6.1 yet. A workaround for dealing with it can be found at https://forums.adobe.com/message/5012581.

Comment: the work around mentioned in adobe forums should work.